# ajax not passing array to controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass the ids of the checked boxes to the controller using ajax. Here is the jquery:

```
function compareEvents() {
        var selected = new Array();
        $('input:checked').each(function () {
            selected.push($(this).attr('id'));
            alert("Event " + $(this).attr('id') + " will be compared");
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Event/CompareEvents",
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            type: "POST",
            datatype: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify({eventIds:selected}),
            error: function (xmlHttpRequest, errorText, thrownError) {
                alert(xmlHttpRequest, errorText, thrownError);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert("success");
                document.location = data;
            }
        });
```

The alert successfully returns the ids of the checked checkboxes.  And returns a success message upon completion.

Here is the controller method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CompareEvents(List<int> eventIds)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

This gets called successfully, except when i debug, `eventIds` is returning `null`.  Can anyone see why `eventIds` is not getting the correct values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sending JSON:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ eventIds:selected }),
```

and setting the contentType header to `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`.

Be consistent with what you are sending:

```
contentType: "application/json",
```

Also there's no such setting called `datatype`. The actual setting is `dataType` but it is redundant because if your controller action is setting the Content-Type response header to `application/json` (which it normally should if you are returning a `JsonResult`), jQuery is intelligent enough to use this header and process the response from the server and pass an already parsed object to your success callback.